# Show title or span in select box (Cakephp 1.3)?

Tags: php, html, cakephp

**Problem**

Show lengthy options on mouse hover in select box with a fixed width.

Names are hidden here:
[image: Names hidden here]

*Rendered HTML in browser*

```
<select id="prim" size="5" multiple="multiple" scroabble="1" name="prim[]">
<option value="Applied Research Associates Inc.">Applied Research Associates Inc.</option>
</select>
```

**Required Output**

Show `span` or `title` as below

[image]

*Expected HTML*

```
<select id="prim" size="5" multiple="multiple" scroabble="1" name="prim[]">
<option value="Applied Research Associates Inc." title="Applied Research Associates Inc.">Applied Research Associates Inc.</option>
</select>
```

**My CakePHP Code**

```
    echo $form->input('prim',
                      array('options'=>$refined_list,
                            'type'=>'select',
                             'scrollable'=>true,
                             'multiple'=>true,
                             'name'=>'prim',
                             'label'=>false,
                             'size'=>'5'));
```

What attribute should I add to make desired changes?

**EDIT/UPDATE:** One way might be to update my `$refined_list` array with `title` field as suggested by *@ammu*. I must wait for a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such way to add attribute to select option in cakephp documentation.Have a look at this, it might help you for adding attributes to select option.

http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/03/01/some-new-crazy-cakephp-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

Well use it like this and you'll get what you want:

```
$options = array(
    ...
    array('name' => 'United states', 'value' => 'USA', 'title' => 'the title that you want'),
    array('name' => 'USA', 'value' => 'USA', 'title' => 'the other title that you want'),
 );

 echo $this->Form->input('test', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$options));
```

you can also add any attribute that you want in the form of array for each option (class, placeholder, etc).

Comment: `$refined_list` array is generated by `cakephp` `find('list')` method so I have to edit my array once again after generation...

Comment: yes but i think it's not a big deal just a foreach statement. or maybe you can change the structure by $params.

Comment: I don't want to increase size of my `$refined_list` array by replication same value for `title` and `value` field.